# How to redirect to edit.php page after saving the post,product and showing the message "post saved "

Tags: plugins

I am trying to redirect all post pages, once a post or products are saved.
It is redirecting to that page but it is not showing any message.
Let me know how to register message for particular pages at admin side.

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'ccl', 99);
function ccl($data) {
    if ($data['post_type'] !== 'revision' && $data['post_status'] == 'publish') {
        $data['post_status'] = 'draft';
        add_filter('redirect_post_location', 'my_redirect_post_location_filter', 99);
    }
    return $data;
}
function my_redirect_post_location_filter($location) {
    remove_filter('redirect_post_location', __FUNCTION__, 99);
    $url='http://legalpropertieshub.com/master/wp-admin/edit.php';
    $location = add_query_arg('message', 99, $url);
    return $location;
}
add_filter('post_updated_messages', 'my_post_updated_messages_filter');
function my_post_updated_messages_filter($messages) {
    $messages['post'][99] = 'Publish not allowed';
    return $messages;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use filter `post_updated_messages` :

```
//Message handling when updating posts
function set_messages($messages) {    
    global $post, $post_ID;
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_ID );

    $obj = get_post_type_object($post_type);
    $singular = $obj->labels->singular_name;

    $messages[$post_type] = array(
        0 => '', // Unused.
        1 => sprintf( __($singular.' uppdaterad. <a href="%s">Visa '.strtolower($singular).'</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
        2 => __('Custom field uppdaterad.'),
        3 => __('Custom field borttagen.'),
        4 => __($singular.' uppdaterad.'),
        5 => isset($_GET['revision']) ? sprintf( __($singular.' återställd till revision från %s'), wp_post_revision_title( (int) $_GET['revision'], false ) ) : false,
        6 => sprintf( __($singular.' publicerad. <a href="%s">Visa '.strtolower($singular).'</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
        7 => __('Sida sparad.'),
        8 => sprintf( __($singular.' skickad. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Förhandsgranska '.strtolower($singular).'</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
        9 => sprintf( __($singular.' schemalagd för: <strong>%1$s</strong>. <a target="_blank" href="%2$s">Förhandsgranska '.strtolower($singular).'</a>'), date_i18n( __( 'M j, Y @ G:i' ), strtotime( $post->post_date ) ), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
        10 => sprintf( __($singular.' utkast uppdaterad. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Förhandsgranska '.strtolower($singular).'</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
    );

    //Special conditions, other messages based on which post-type when updating
    if ($obj->name == 'product') {    
        //Do something
    }

    return $messages;
}
//Set messages array for posts. Special cases are handled based on post-type
add_filter('post_updated_messages', 'set_messages');
```

Comment: i am new to the wp. will you explain more.will u suggest me wp developer tutorials. does it navigate to all post page or not.

Answer (score 0):

I added this hook to function.php file. "function.php" file is located inside your theme folder, copy this code, paste it inside the file and save.

```
add_action('save_post','redirect_page');
    function redirect_page(){
    $type=  get_post_type();

    switch ($type){
    case "post":
        $url=  admin_url().'edit.php?msg=post';
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    break;
    case "product":
        $url=  admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=product&msg=page';
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    break;
    case "page":
        $url=  admin_url().'edit.php?post_type=page&msg=page';
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    break;
    }
}
```

after that below code to wp-admin/edit.php line 272

```
if(isset($_GET['msg'])){
$type1=$_GET['msg'];
switch ($type1){
    case "post":
    echo '<div id="message" class="updated"><p>Post Saved</p></div>';
    break;
    case "product":
    echo '<div id="message" class="updated"><p>Product Saved</p></div>';
    break;
    case "page":
    echo '<div id="message" class="updated"><p>Page Saved</p></div>';
    break;
    }

}
```

anyone let me know the better way to do this.